# How can VLC play 24-bit PCM audio on general PC?

Tags: audio, vlc, naudio, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I've tried to play out an 24 bit PCM audio(s24le) by using [Vlcsharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) and [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

I set audio play callback by calling [libvlc_audio_set_callbacks()](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gaac7abb1d8be3f60bb9da20c000703790) to get raw sample data firstly.

Next, I tried two sample video. The one has 24-bit PCM audio, and the another has 16-bit one(converted by using ffmpeg CLI from 24-bit), except of it, everything is the same.
They're played well, but when I saw the data by debugger, the sample data got by [vlc's audio play callback](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga9a242251d11378ecdc43b8ef0cc0254e) is the same.

After some researches, I found out the general PC can't play 24-bit PCM audio without a proper sound card.

If It's right, Is there some bit-depth convert(24->16) process to play? so, the sample data got by callback is same?

Comment: It's probably been a decade since I've seen even a basic PC sound card that didn't support 24-bit.  However, it isn't always enabled.  I'm not familiar with the API your'e using, but it sounds like it's also going to be dependent on the VLC output plugin and OS.

Comment: Does that work with VLC? It sounds more like an issue with NAudio than VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the format parameter here if you wanted to force vlc to convert the format :
https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/blob/master/AudioCallbacks/Program.cs#L59

```
int AudioSetup(ref IntPtr opaque, ref IntPtr format, ref uint rate, ref uint channels)
```

see the doc [here](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gab41121b9dae9dae89a655290d1b74fd7)
format should be a 4 ascii chars string, but I don't know the available formats you can pass here.

Comment: I've solved it by convert the format as you proposed. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please post your resulting code as an answer if anyone else has the same issue.